# How do I make a method go to the main method in java?

Tags: java

I am actually having *more* problems within java - like I am letting the parameters within a standard method, not the main, and making it so it can return to the main method. Here is my code for actually doing so:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class boxtype {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String[] melee = {"Crowbar", "Bowie Knife", "Butterfly Knife", "Knuckleduster"};
    String[] pistol = {"Colt .22", "Magnum .45", "P250", "9mm Pistol"};
    String[] assault = {"AK47", "M4A1", "M16", "SMG", "Mac10", "Minigun (HGE)"};
    String[] shotgunsniper = {"Shotgun", "Benelli S90", "Sniper Rifle"};
    String[] attachments = {"Laser Sight", "Silencer", "Scope", "Auto-target"};
    System.out.println("TypeClass loader - type 'help' for help");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String xy = scan.nextLine();
    if (xy.equals("spyclass")) {
        spyClass(assault, attachments, pistol, melee);
    }

}

private static void spyClass(String[] assault, String[] pistol, String[] attachments, String[] melee) {     
    System.out.println("Spy class: ");
    System.out.println("Primary weapon: " + assault[1] + " + " + attachments[1]);
    System.out.println("Secondary weapon: " + pistol[0] + " + " + attachments[1]);
    System.out.println("Melee Weapon: " + melee[2]);
}

private static void helpeur() {
    System.out.println("spyclass - goes to the spy class");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String xy = scan.nextLine();
    if (xy.equals("main menu")) {
        main(String[] args);
    }
}

}
```

But it says that "String args[] is not a declared variable" and I run Eclipse.

Comment: String[] args, maybe?

Comment: You are calling `main` method in a wrong way in `helpeur` method

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve by calling main method. But here is how you can do this:

```
    main(new String[1]);
```

instead of

```
   main(String[] args);
```

Main method is a special method, which is used by JVM as the entry point for starting an application code. So calling in the code is legal but not advisable. I would recommend you to move your code to a different method to present menu options.

Comment: Does this mean code in the main method can be executed more than once?

Comment: @BradySheehan yeah syntatically, main method is a static method and can be called from a static context.

Answer (score 0):

You can't (well, maybe you can but you shouldn't) call the main method inside your program. Instead consider adding some kind of `start()` method that contains the code inside your main method. Then you could just do this:

```
if (xy.equals("main menu")) {
    start();
}
```

By the way, the reason that you were getting an error is because

```
String[] args
```

Doesn't have a value so it can't be passed as a parameter.